Accuracy of Instructions for a Student to Act as a Qubit for the CHSH Game
My goal
I am an educator attempting to demonstrate an optimal quantum strategy for the CHSH game in a math club meeting of students. Students will play the roles of Alice, Bob, the Referee, and Qubits.
Teaching students how to play Alice, Bob, and the Referee are not that difficult. I am interested in how to have students "play" as the qubits.
My question
Does my implementation of a qubit below look accurate?
$\def\ket#1{|{#1}\rangle}$ I am interested in suggestions on how to make the calculations simpler for students but I am mostly interested in whether my implementation will work technically correctly and whether my terminology is accurate.
I am following the idea in this exposition ("Walking the faster-than-light tightrope" by Andrew Helwer) that after a qubit's state has collapsed, it can be represented by an angle on the unit circle, with the angle $0$ representing $\ket0$ and the angle $\frac{\pi}{2}$ representing $\ket1$, with $\frac{\pi}{4}$ being $\ket+$ and $-\frac{\pi}{4}$ being $\ket-$. I am using this primarily to keep the necessary level of mathematics and physics low. If this simplification ruins everything though, I would love to know that.
How to play as a collapsed qubit
You are a collapsed qubit. You can only keep track of one piece of information: your state $T$, which is an angle like $0$ or $\frac{\pi}{8}$ or $\frac{\pi}{2}$. Keep track of your state $T$. You will need it to answer questions about yourself.
When someone measures you, they will ask you whether you are one of two angles: $\theta_0$ and $\theta_1$, which are 90 degrees apart. Don't tell them what angle you are! You only get to answer either $\theta_0$ or $\theta_1$.

You should say you are $\theta_0$ with probability $\cos^2(T -
    \theta_0)$ and say you are $\theta_1$ with probability $\cos^2(T -
    \theta_1)$.
After you answer, change your state to the one you
answered, so that you told the truth.

How to play as a Bell State entangled qubit
Your state is a little strange, because it has a 50% chance of being the angle $0$ and a 50% chance of being the angle $\frac{\pi}{2}$. Don't decide what you are until someone measures you!
You are also entangled with another qubit. Stay close to that person; the first time someone measures one of you, it will change both your states. After that, you will just be a collapsed qubit (see the other instructions for how to play as a collapsed qubit).
When someone measures you, they will ask whether you are one of two angles: $\theta_0$ and $\theta_1$, which are 90 degrees apart. Don't tell them what angle you are! You only get to answer either $\theta_0$ or $\theta_1$.

First, decide whether you are $0$ or $\frac{\pi}{2}$ with
probability 50% each and temporarily set your state $T$ to that
value.
Then answer that you are $\theta_0$ with probability
$\cos^2(T - \theta_0)$ and say you are $\theta_1$ with probability
$\cos^2(T - \theta_1)$.
After you answer, change your state $T$ to the
one you answered, so that you told the truth.
Then tell your entangled pair what their new state is. You should now both be
collapsed qubits that are in the same state.
Separate from your entangled pair and don't talk to them anymore.

